# Copy and past URL in JSP is giving white page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am new to this forum. I have a doubt about JSP/servlet in my application
I have developed an application in which user may search some data based on some criteria and he will get data from database(through Hibernate to servlet and to JSP). When some data is displayed on screen based on search he/she may try to copy the URL and forward to anyone or If he try to open in different browser it is showing an empty page.
eg: if i try to paste the link given bellow it is showing blank page
  [example link](http://egarnet.com/JP/jobsearchresult.jsp)
but i need to display the data how this can be achieved.

Edited: After clicking on job search in menu bar as mentioned in comments the page will redirect to a servlet

```
 if(action.equals("searchjob")){
            String requireskills=request.getParameter("txt_requireSkills");
             String location=request.getParameter("txt_locationName");
             session.setAttribute("location",location);
             String minexp1=request.getParameter("dd_minimum");
             String maxexp1=request.getParameter("dd_maximum");
             jobsearchDAO = new JobSearchDAOImpl(); 

            List<JobPostInfo> data=jobsearchDAO.jobsearchlist(requireskills,location,minexp1,maxexp1);

            if(data!=null && data.size()!=0){
                //save data



              if(!(session.getAttribute("LoginObject")==null)){
                JobSeeker jobSeeker=(JobSeeker)session.getAttribute("LoginObject");

                JobSearchCriteria jobsearchcriteria= new JobSearchCriteria();
                jobsearchDAO=new JobSearchDAOImpl();

                 jobsearchcriteria.setKeyWords(requireskills);
                 jobsearchcriteria.setLocation(location);

                JobSeeker jobseeker=(JobSeeker)session.getAttribute("jobseeker");
               // 
               // jobsearchcriteria.setJobSeeker(jobseeker.getJobSeekerSn()); 


               jobsearchcriteria.setJscTs(new Date());
                int value=jobsearchDAO.savesearch(jobsearchcriteria);
                 System.out.println("savesearch value------>"+value);

                }


                    session.setAttribute("jobsearchlist", data);

                  //  session.setAttribute("success","Search Criteria is saved to database."); 

                response.sendRedirect("jobsearchresult.jsp");
                }else 
                {

                  session.setAttribute("error","No Records found");

                   response.sendRedirect("jobsearch.jsp");
                }

        }
```

This is the code in DAOIMPL

```
     public List<JobPostInfo> jobsearchlist(String requireskills,String location,String minexp1,String maxexp1) throws Exception{
     long minexp;
     long maxexp;

       try{
             session =getSession();
            //Criteria Query
            Criteria query=session.createCriteria(JobPostInfo.class,"jpost");



          // if(minexp1.equals("0") && (maxexp1.equals("") || maxexp1==null)){
          if((minexp1.equals("-1")  || minexp1=="-1") && maxexp1==null){

           }
          else if(minexp1.equals("0")){

                minexp=Long.parseLong(minexp1);
                long min=1;
                query.add(Restrictions.lt("jpost.experienceMin",min)); 
           }else if(!(minexp1.equals("") || minexp1==null) && maxexp1.equals("-1")) {

                    minexp=Long.parseLong(minexp1);
                    query.add(Restrictions.ge("jpost.experienceMin",minexp));  
           }else if(!(minexp1==null && maxexp1==null)){

                   minexp=Long.parseLong(minexp1);
                   maxexp=Long.parseLong(maxexp1);
                   query.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ge("jpost.experienceMin",minexp),Restrictions.le("jpost.experienceMax",maxexp)));
               }   



             //For Location 

                 if(!(location==null|| location.equals(""))){
                                    query.createAlias("jpost.location","location");
                                    query.add(Restrictions.like("location.locationName",location).ignoreCase());

                 }
            //For Keyword
             if(!(requireskills==null || requireskills.equals(""))){


                     query.add(Restrictions.like("jpost.requiredSkills","%"+requireskills+"%").ignoreCase());
                 }//requireskills

             List<JobPostInfo> list = query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();



             if(list.size()==0){
             return null;
             }else{
                 return list;
                 }

             }catch(HibernateException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
             }finally {
             close(session);
             }
             return null;


 }
```

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? What error messages are in the logs? Your question breeds questions and is not answerable in its current form.

Comment: The example link is what i have developed. Go-to egarnet.com/JP and in menu bar type click job search and click search it will get the data from DB.

Comment: Can you give me any links or pages to solve this kind of problems. I have noticed the stackoverflow site each question is comming with a perticular number and fallowed by the heading of question. is that number is specific to perticular question. so that when user copy and paste link it will get that perticular data from DB.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The link is to a JSP with no parameters, and no identifying characteristics in the link--what would your code search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It's a very basic mistake and I hope this will help others:

`response.sendRedirect("jobsearchresult.jsp")` is replaced by `request.getRequestDispatcher("studentinformation.jsp").forward(request, response)`

or `include`-method. The second thing is, the session is created and initialized with the servlet. When I copy the link in a different browser, a certain block of the servlet will be executed. *Example*:

> action.equals("searchjob")

So at the time the session is not available yet, I initialize it in every block like separating declaration and initialization.